# getting only the names of the contacts when importing .csv file to my yahoo contacts?

Tags: iphone, csv, contacts, yahoo-mail

i have been trying to import my contacts from my personal computer by converting them the .xlsx to .csv format and only the contact names are imported instead of the whole contact.my excel file is taken from the backup contacts from iphone .

Comment: If you look at the CSV, does it include only the name?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds to me as if you have not set up the fields properly so that the .csv file is not copying all the information you need.

Both export and import fields need to match.